# ListView’s image column passes null value to Database

Tags: asp.net

I am inserting an *image* to my database by using `ListView` control and `EntityDataSource`. In the `InsertItemTemplate` are  `Image` and `FileUpload` Controls in the MemberImage column. After I have inserted data,  the image column shows null in the database.

Any approach for the correct procedure will be appreciated.

My code snippet is as seen below:

```
<asp:ListView ID="IndividualListView" runat="server"  DataKeyNames="IndividualId" DataSourceID="IndividualDataSource"  InsertItemPosition="LastItem"

    oniteminserting="IndividualListView_ItemInserting"
    onselectedindexchanged="IndividualListView_SelectedIndexChanged">

    <InsertItemTemplate>     
        <td>   
            <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert"
                Text="Insert" BorderStyle="Ridge" />

            <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel"
                Text="Clear" BorderStyle="Ridge" />    
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="IndividualIdTextBox" runat="server"
                Text='<%# Bind("IndividualId") %>' />    
        </td>    
        <td>                              
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("MemberImage") %>'/><br />

            <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" /><br />

            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>

        </td>

     </InsertItemTemplate>    
 </asp:ListView>

 <asp:EntityDataSource ID="IndividualDataSource" runat="server"    
     ConnectionString="name=SheepGateEntities"    
     DefaultContainerName="SheepGateEntities" EnableDelete="True"  
     EnableInsert="True" EnableUpdate="True" EntitySetName="Individuals"    
     EntityTypeFilter="Individual" Include="Counsellings, Households, Services">    
 </asp:EntityDataSource>
```

Code behind page is as follows:

```
protected void IndividualListView_ItemInserting(object sender, ListViewInsertEventArgs e)
{
    FUpload = (FileUpload)IndividualListView.InsertItem.FindControl("FileUpload1");
    FLabel = (Label)IndividualListView.InsertItem.FindControl("Label1");             

    try
    {                 
        FileUpload img = (FileUpload)FUpload;
        Byte[] imgByte = null;

        if (img.HasFile && img.PostedFile != null)
        {
            //To create a PostedFile

            HttpPostedFile File = FUpload.PostedFile; 
            imgByte = new Byte[File.ContentLength];

            //force the control to load data in array
            File.InputStream.Read(imgByte, 0, File.ContentLength);
        }
        e.Values.Add("MemberImage", FUpload.FileName);

    }
    catch
    {
        FLabel.BackColor.Equals("Red");
        FLabel.Text = "There was an error";
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried debugging? does 'if (img.HasFile && img.PostedFile != null)' evaluates to true? A bit more info would be nice.

Comment: Just a suggestion. Consider storing images path in database instead of images.

Comment: Just Edited the original code. The idea here is using the FileUpload Control inside the ItemTemplate of a ListView to upload an image and pass the image value to a database. Referencing my original code posted here, On debugging everything is correct execpt this line :  e.Values.Add("MemberImage", imgByte); Am using the ListView ItemInserting event to add the value to be passed to the database. Here, "MmemberImage" represents the key of the element to add and "imgByte" is represent the image value.

Comment: Hi KPL, what do you mean by consider storing images path in database instead of images?. Did you read my original post well? None of my code snippet shows storage of information within images. My code clearly shows that all will be stored in a database. Thank you